# SQL rows dissapear when join added

Tags: sql, inner-join

```
SELECT     tblArtworkTemplates.ID, tblArtworkTemplates.dateCreated, tblSpecifications.TxtPagination, tblSpecifications.FlatSizeW AS width, 
                      tblSpecifications.FlatSizeL AS length, tblSpecifications.FlatSizeUOM AS uom,
                          (SELECT     COUNT(1) AS Expr1
                            FROM          tblArtworkUploads
                            WHERE      (templateID = tblArtworkTemplates.ID)) AS uploadCount,
                          (SELECT     COUNT(1) AS talks
                            FROM          tblArtworkTemplateMessages
                            WHERE      (templateID = tblArtworkTemplates.ID)) AS talkCount, tblArtworkTemplates.lastEditPing, tblUsers.userName AS Expr1
FROM         tblUsers INNER JOIN
                      tblArtworkTemplates INNER JOIN
                      tblSpecifications ON tblArtworkTemplates.specID = tblSpecifications.id ON tblUsers.id = tblArtworkTemplates.editPingUserID
WHERE     (tblArtworkTemplates.userID = 70)
```

The tblusers join is causing rows to disapear when tblArtworkTemplates.editPingUserID is null.  Am I using the wrong sort of join type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try a left outer join.. Or a Right outer join..

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) for informations about join

Comment: Thanks, right outer join works.  These things always confuse the hell out of me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, your join was wrong.

```
SELECT     tblArtworkTemplates.ID, tblArtworkTemplates.dateCreated, tblSpecifications.TxtPagination, tblSpecifications.FlatSizeW AS width, 
                      tblSpecifications.FlatSizeL AS length, tblSpecifications.FlatSizeUOM AS uom,
                          (SELECT     COUNT(1) AS Expr1
                            FROM          tblArtworkUploads
                            WHERE      (templateID = tblArtworkTemplates.ID)) AS uploadCount,
                          (SELECT     COUNT(1) AS talks
                            FROM          tblArtworkTemplateMessages
                            WHERE      (templateID = tblArtworkTemplates.ID)) AS talkCount, tblArtworkTemplates.lastEditPing, tblUsers.userName AS Expr1
FROM tblUsers u 
    INNER JOIN tblArtworkTemplates a ON  u.id = a.editPingUserID
    INNER JOIN tblSpecifications s ON a.specID = s.id ON
WHERE     (a.userID = 70)
```

Comment: the join wasn't "wrong" if you are referring to the double-on clause after the double-join. It works and is valid syntax

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are after.

If you always want records from tblUsers, but data from Template+Specification only where data is available from both *(in other words, if a Template doesn't have a Specification, you don't care about the Template)*, use this

```
FROM tblUsers
LEFT JOIN
        tblArtworkTemplates
        INNER JOIN tblSpecifications
            ON tblArtworkTemplates.specID = tblSpecifications.id
    ON tblUsers.id = tblArtworkTemplates.editPingUserID
```

If you always want records from tblUsers, but data from Template if available, and then from Specification if available *(in other words, if a Template is available that has no Specification, get data from the Template record anyway)*, then use this

```
FROM tblUsers
LEFT JOIN
        tblArtworkTemplates
        LEFT JOIN tblSpecifications
            ON tblArtworkTemplates.specID = tblSpecifications.id
    ON tblUsers.id = tblArtworkTemplates.editPingUserID
```

or more commonly written (since the 2 left joins are commutative)

```
FROM tblUsers
LEFT JOIN tblArtworkTemplates
    ON tblUsers.id = tblArtworkTemplates.editPingUserID
LEFT JOIN tblSpecifications
    ON tblArtworkTemplates.specID = tblSpecifications.id
```